# Clustering groups to use in Bayesian regression

Tags: statistics, bayesian, usage-statistics

I'm using clustering to identify different groups in a certain dataset. I then plan to use the groups I find as group-variable in a Bayesian logistic multilevel model.

My question is if using some of the variables I use in theclustering process in the fitting of the model will create problems? Do I have to use different variables in my model than when clustering the different groups?